# Usage of AND for multiple times in a single statement

Tags: verbs, prepositions, conjunctions

Peak voltage, peak current, average voltage, and average current are four different things. Can I write them in the following way? I am confused with the usage of AND in this case.

**Peak and average voltage and current** analysis can be done using a Picoscope.

Comment: No. It introduces ambiguity.  'Peak and average voltage analysis, and peak and average  current analysis, can all be done using a Picoscope.' Though I'd stick with 'The analysis of peak and average voltage, and peak and average current, can all be done using a Picoscope.'

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can put it that way, and it's better. It might even be clearer like this:

> Peak and average analyses of voltage and current can be done with a Picoscope.

Comment: Wow! Nice idea. Thanks mate!

Comment: I wouldn't say "peak and average voltage and current analysis" is necessarily better: it could be misinterpreted to as "[peak and average voltage] and [current] analysis". I don't think your rephrased version has the same problem though.

Comment: @nnnnnn  I think that for those interested in the Picoscope, "peak and average" and "voltage and current" are such natural pairs that the misinterpretation is unlikely.